# How to Have Spring Pass Subclasses to Creation of JAXBContext?

Tags: java, xml, spring, inheritance, jaxb

My problem is usually solved with @XmlSeeAlso, but I can't do that in this case because the child and super class are in 2 different projects.

```
Parent Project
- AbstractParent ( property = commonProperty )
- WrapperObject ( property = AbstractParent, other properties )

Child Project
- includes Parent Project
- ConcereteChild extends AbstractParent ( property = extraProperty )

Service Project
- includes Parent Project and Child Project
```

Service Project is a Spring-based project that uses HttpMessageConverter defined in the applicationContext.xml - in the org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller bean instantiation, I used "packagesToScan" property and include BOTH the AbstractParent package and ConcreteChild package.

Service Project instantiate ConcreteChild and then put it into WrapperObject  which is then returned by the Controller class and let the Spring message converter to convert it to XML.

My problem:
When Spring does the object conversion on WrapperObject, it only sees AbstractParent properties, it does not see ConcreteChild properties at all.

This usually solved with @XmlSeeAlso on AbstractParent, but because the Parent Project does not include (and cannot include) Child Project, I can't make use of @XmlSeeAlso. Including Child Project into Parent Project will create a cycle.

Is there a way around this?

**UPDATE**

All the threads that I found always talk about adding @XmlSeeAlso - which again, is impossible for me because the parent and subclass are in 2 different projects.

I tested with:

```
Class[] cs = new Class[2];
cs[0] = ConcreteChild.class;
cs[1] = WrapperObject.class;

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(cs);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();


ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
marshaller.marshal(responseDTO, baos);

String xmlStr= new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

and the above code works just fine, the resulting "xmlStr" produces the approppriate XML with the ConcreteChild (instead of just the AbstractParent). the resulting xml has the xsi:type as well to specify the ConreteChild

I have also retrieve the Jaxb2Marshaller from my Spring context and print out the list of classes bound to the marshaller, and it already included the ConcreteChild - But the resulting XML from Spring's HttpMessageConverter still ignores it, it only includes AbstractParent - and it doesn't have the xsi:type.

***So something is weird going on with the Jaxb processing done by Spring?***

Additionally - I tried removing all values from packagesToScan on the Jaxb configuration in Spring applicationContext.xml - it will complain that packagesToScan cannot be empty (expected behaviour), so I add a String value pointing to a package that has NOTHING to do with my objects: WrapperObject / AbstractParent / ConcreteChild - magically, the Spring HTTP Message converter still works !

So really, there's something weird with the HTTP Message conversion by Spring?

Comment: @blaise - I see your edit on the title, but I don't think the issue is about passing subclasses to JaxbContext - as I described, I already uses packagesToScan when creating the JaxbContext, hence it should already picked up the sublcasses, unless I am missing something?

Comment: The symptoms of your problem seem to indicate that the results of scanning the package are not being passed to the creation of the `JAXBContext`.  Are you sure this part is working?

Comment: I print out the list of classes from my injected JaxbContext and the ConcreteChild is there, in fact the AbstractParent isn't listed there. The issue is WrapperObject property type is AbstractParent, and it doesnt seem to resolve it to the child class type.